# My live site page has unaligned

Tags: magento2.3, command-line

It's urgent my live site website has unaligned after running;
 `"sudo bin/magento-cli setup:static-content:deploy"` command.

All page alignment has changed.
Please help to fix this solution.

Please check the image below for my unaligned website. (CSS and js file are not loading)
[image]

Comment: can you add screenshot, also please check consol log for errors hint

Comment: Please check my updated question.

Comment: did you check the browser console for some error logs

Comment: Please let me know how to check that

Comment: right click on your website page , then choose inspect, then click on Console tab

Comment: http://prntscr.com/o09h97

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/94743/discussion-between-mohana-and-fmsthird).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To solve this issue you can backup your generated/ pub/static/ var/cache/folders and delete them for once. Now run below command again.

```
sudo bin/magento-cli setup:static-content:deploy -f
```

Comment: I think the command should also include the en_GB language pack

Comment: Yeah we can include en_GB language pack. But with this also it will work.

Comment: but her site is using english uk locale without specifying the en_GB will result to some css issue

Answer (score 1):

You can try to run deploy static command for a specific language:

```
sudo bin/magento-cli setup:static-content:deploy -f en_GB
```

Comment: Please let me now what is the use for above command?

Comment: it will redeploy static contents specific for the english UK (en_GB) -f to force redeploy

Comment: Okay, now running the command, let you know once completed